# How to retrieve for the entire universe past performance, shareholder friendliness and cheapness metrics?

Tags: value-investing

I recently read [Good Stocks Cheap](https://books.google.com.au/books/about/Good_Stocks_Cheap_Value_Investing_with_C.html?id=60UkDwAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) (and took a [course](https://continuingstudies.stanford.edu/courses/professional-and-personal-development/value-investing-an-introduction/20191_BUS-123-W) run by the author). I have summarised in a [table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JmaGhonxfEjxuo0lFVlLxCDbLTRv4-1ZO89wrTiWbKU/edit?usp=sharing) attached to this post the past performance, shareholder friendliness and cheapness benchmarks he recommends. Does anyone know how to automatically extract companies meeting these benchmarks?

[image]